Issue with Dark and Light Mode in Chart.js using react-chartjs-2 with React, TypeScript, Vite, and Bootstrap
I'm working on a React project with TypeScript, Vite, and Bootstrap, and I'm using react-chartjs-2 and Chart.js to display a bar chart. The chart is displayed correctly, but I'm having trouble setting up dynamic themes (dark and light mode) based on the value of isDarkMode.
In my code, I retrieve the isDarkMode value as a boolean from the ConfigContext. I want to dynamically change the chart's appearance, particularly the background and text colors in the tooltip, based on whether dark mode is enabled. However, the current implementation doesn't seem to be fully responsive to dark and light mode changes.
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

// Project imports
import { ConfigContext } from 'contexts/ConfigContext';

// Third-party imports
import { Chart as ChartJS, CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Tooltip, Legend } from 'chart.js';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

ChartJS.register(CategoryScale, LinearScale, BarElement, Tooltip, Legend);

const labels = [0, 1, 2, 3];

const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Data 1',
      data: [25, 45, 74, 85],
      backgroundColor: '#7267ef'
    },
    {
      label: 'Data 2',
      data: [30, 52, 65, 65],
      backgroundColor: '#17c666'
    }
  ]
};

export default function BarBasicChart(): React.ReactElement {
  const configContext = useContext(ConfigContext);
  const { pageType } = configContext.state;

  // Determine if the current mode is dark
  const isDarkMode = pageType === 'app-dark-mode';

  // Create options dynamically based on isDarkMode
  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top' as const
      },
      tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)', // Tooltip background based on dark mode
        titleColor: isDarkMode ? 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)', // Tooltip title color
        bodyColor: isDarkMode ? 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)' // Tooltip body text color
      }
    }
  };

  return <Bar options={options} data={data} />;
}

problem:
I want to make the chart's tooltip responsive to dark and light modes based on the isDarkMode value. However, I'm not sure if this is the correct way to implement the dark/light mode functionality in Chart.js, and the tooltip colors aren't updating as expected when the mode switches.
Questions:

Is there a better way to handle dark and light modes for Chart.js
tooltips in a React project?
Are there any best practices I should
follow to make the chart fully responsive to theme changes?
How can
I ensure that the chart re-renders correctly when the theme is
toggled?


You should use the redraw property, to allow your chart to be rerendered :
<Bar options={options} data={data} redraw/>

However, using redraw re-triggers the initial animation, which is likely unwanted

But actually your chart should rerender on the options change by default. I have here a small reproducible example, where after 5 secs, I change the label position, and the Chart rerender without any further config: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/zen-albattani-dv4jmj
So I think that you should not even need to use redraw
